# Can't find the error in debug manifest?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Below you can see the manifest file I am using in my app. It has some error and its not compiling. I am not able to figure out the error.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.practice.vengicx.locatecash">
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBuVtdAa57JQb9onxgyZ4we5VrRT9xvHqQ"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application> 
</manifest>
```

The error is something like:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
Attribute uses-feature#@integer/google_play_services_version@glEsVersi‌​on at AndroidManifest.xml:4:19-78 is not a valid hexadecimal 32 bit value, found @integer/google_play_services_version
```

Comment: can you show what error you are getting? Also avoid putting your api keys in stackoverflow

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: Attribute uses-feature#@integer/google_play_services_version@glEsVersion at AndroidManifest.xml:4:19-78 is not a valid hexadecimal 32 bit value, found @integer/google_play_services_version

Comment: edit the question..better put your log there

Answer (score 1):

`android:glEsVersion="@integer/google_play_services_version"`

That property definitely shouldn't have that value.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#manifest for information about acceptable values.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys it got resolved thanks you very much I used glEsVersion as 0x00020000